# write DefaultCategoryDataset value into file

Tags: java, jfreechart

I use jfree chart in my program. I use `DefaultCategoryDataset` to save data that i want to show in my chart. Now i want to writ `DefaultCategoryDataset` values include list of columns,rows and value. 
anyone know how can i do this??

```java
frame = new JFrame();
frame.setBounds(50, 50, 1135, 1029);

DefaultCategoryDataset dataSet = new DefaultCategoryDataset(); 
for (int i = 0; i < observedEWMAs.size(); i++) {
 dataSet.addValue(observedEWMAs.get(i), "observed" + title,
          ((Integer) (i + 1)).toString()); 
//here i want to write data set fo file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`DefaultCategoryDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/category/DefaultCategoryDataset.html) defined in [`BarChartDemo1`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/demo/BarChartDemo1.html), seen [here](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/demo/BarChartDemo1.html#line.97), the following code produces the expected output:

Code:

```
for (int r = 0; r < dataset.getRowCount(); r++) {
    String series = (String) dataset.getRowKey(r);
    for (int c = 0; c < dataset.getColumnCount(); c++) {
        System.out.println(series
            + ", " + dataset.getColumnKey(c)
            + ", " + dataset.getValue(r, c));
    }
}
```

Console:

```
First, Category 1, 1.0
First, Category 2, 4.0
First, Category 3, 3.0
First, Category 4, 5.0
First, Category 5, 5.0
Second, Category 1, 5.0
Second, Category 2, 7.0
Second, Category 3, 6.0
Second, Category 4, 8.0
Second, Category 5, 4.0
Third, Category 1, 4.0
Third, Category 2, 3.0
Third, Category 3, 2.0
Third, Category 4, 3.0
Third, Category 5, 6.0
```